# unable to display the entire link list only displays the last element in link list in c

Tags: c

i am trying to create a singly link list but while displaying it stores the last entered value only the first entered value goes missing
for ex:
if i am entering 1 node or 1 element it works fine but as soon as i enter 2 elements it displays only the last entered value the first value goes missing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
};
struct node *create(struct node *head,int data)
{
    if(head->next==NULL)
    {
    head->data=data;
    head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
    head=head->next;
    head->data=data;
    head->next=NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
void display(struct node * head)
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
    printf("%d",head->data);
    head=head->next;
    }
}
main()
{
    struct node *head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)),*head1;
    int n,data,i;
    printf("\n enter how many elements ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("enter data");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        head=create(head,data); 
    }
    display(head);  
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the below linked list create function and get the required result.

To solve that you need to assign `struct node *head=NULL` and use the below create function.

**Create Function:**

```
struct node *create(struct node *head,int value)
{
   struct node *temp;
   /* updated code start */
   if(head == NULL)
   {
      head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      temp->data=value;
      temp->next=NULL;
   }
   else
   {
   /*Updated code ends */
      temp=head;
      while(temp->next != NULL)
      temp=temp->next;
      temp->next=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      if (temp->next !=NULL)
      {
         temp=temp->link;
         temp->data=value;
         temp->next=NULL;
      }
   }
   return head;
}
```

**Update:**

Due to memory allocation unable to find whether the first position is empty or not.
we can also do something in for statement before calling the create function, like

```
if(i==0)
{
  head->data=value;
  head->next=NULL;
  continue;
}
```

The above code is also one of the way to do the same thing with the existing code.

Comment: could you tell me the reason why it displays 0 each time in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `head` in `main()`  is re-assigned to the new, last, element all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There will only ever be one element in your linked list since the only time an element is created is in the first line in your main method.

In the `create()` function, `malloc()` a new element and assign `head->next` to its value, then populate it with `data`.

```
struct node *create(struct node *element, int data)
{
    if (element)
    {
        while(element->next)
        {
            element = element->next;
        }
        element->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        element = element->next;
    }
    else
    {
        element = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    }
    element->data = data;
    return element;
}
```

Now, do not reassign `head` to the returned value from the call to `create()` in `main()`, but if you later want to optimize for some reason, you could always save a `tail` pointer and use that as the parameter to `create()`, so that you will not have to traverse the entire list each time.

Also, not that I haven't compiled this, so there may be some syntactic errors...